# html2pdf freeze UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

Hi i'm using html2pdf on my React project and i'm going through problems when i try to generate the pdf document. 
The problem is that in Android/desktop the UI freeze for a while (time that take to generate pdf file) and then the download work fine. In iphone the UI freeze and never recover, i can't interact with others components like a table or a combo, it only recover if I close the explorer and reopen and when I do that the pdf file appears in the screen with the right format and look.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
const PdfDownloader = (props) => {
  const exportToPDF = (fileName) => {
    let opt = {
      margin: 0.5,
      filename: `${fileName}.pdf`,
      image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98},
      html2canvas: {scale: 2},
      jsPDF: {unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait'}
    };
    html2pdf().set(opt).from(pdfContainerRef.current).save();
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <Button className={styles["max-width-initial"]} block
               onClick={() => exportToPDF('my_crazy_file')}>
            Descargar PDF
        </Button>
     </div>
  )
}
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, or if something missing in my code or i'm in front of a bug.

Comment: I search for this issue in the github repository of the library [link](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues) and i found similar behavior when the PDF file has lot of images or pages and is not my case, i only print a header and raw data in a table

Comment: It's seems that the issue is not the freeze in the iphone UI (the freeze ui is due to the render), instead it's a know problem that occurs at the time that html2pdf (through jsPDF and filesaver) try to download the pdf file.